# Перевод char или String в двоичный код (Java)

Tags: java, строки, char

Ребят, вопрос, в принципе, не такой и сложный, однако, я гуглил, но не нашел толкового ответа.
Как в Java перевести символ (char или даже лучше String) в двоичный код? 
То есть дана строка `Str = "abс";`, нужно перевести её в тот же стринг, но уже двоичным кодом: `1100001 1100010 11010001 10000001`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Для этого есть готовый метод:

```
String a = Integer.toBinaryString('a');
System.out.println(a);
```

Выведет на экран:

```
1100001
```

Соответственно, если необходимо перевести целую строку в двоичный код, а не отдельный символ, можно написать для этого свой метод, например:

```
public String stringToBinary(String s) {

    StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);

        answer.append(Integer.toBinaryString(c)).append(' ');
    }

    return answer.toString();
}
```

Более красивое решение на Java 8:

```
public String stringToBinary(String s) {
    return s
            .chars()
            .collect(StringBuilder::new,
                    (sb, c) -> sb.append(Integer.toBinaryString(c)).append(' '),
                    StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();
}
```